# Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host.FunctionTimeoutException

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azure-durable-functions

We have a durable function, which got timeout exception

```
problemid: Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host.FunctionTimeoutException at Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host.Executors.FunctionExecutor+<TryHandleTimeoutAsync>d__35.MoveNext

outerType: Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host.FunctionTimeoutException

outerMessage: Timeout value of 02:00:00 was exceeded by function: Functions.MultiRecipientActivity
```

This app is running on App Service Plan (P1v2)

```
This is my host.json
{
  "version": "2.0",
  "logging": {
    "applicationInsights": {
      "samplingSettings": {
        "isEnabled": true,
        "excludedTypes": "Request"
      }
    }
  },
  "functionTimeout": "02:00:00",
  "extensionBundle": {
    "id": "Microsoft.Azure.Functions.ExtensionBundle",
    "version": "[2.*, 3.0.0)"
  }
}
```

Please help me resolve this problem.

Comment: Is it locally or in Azure portal? If timeout is in portal function app, what is the hosting plan which has been deployed?

Comment: Azure Portal. App Service Plan is P1v2

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-host-json#functiontimeout - If it is App service plan, keep functionTimeout attribute as unbounded (-1) and try

Answer (score 0):

> `outerMessage: Timeout value of 02:00:00 was exceeded by function: Functions.MultiRecipientActivity`

- If you are hosting the Azure Functions Project in a Dedicated App Service Plan or Premium plan and if **timeout** property is required more than the default (`30 minutes`) then it is recommended to use `-1` value as mentioned in this [MS Doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-host-json#functiontimeout) of Azure Functions Host Configuration.
- I found the similar issue on the GitHub [Repository](https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-durable-extension/issues/1599) of Azure Functions timeout issue were specifying the timeout property more than the default would fail but as recommended by Microsoft i.e., **-1** (unbounded value) for that property is working pretty fine for many customers.

  **Syntax**:

  `"functionTimeout": "-1"`
- The above-mentioned timeout property will be applied on the `host.json` file for the .csx functions (Functions created in the portal environment) and for remaining types of Function projects like C# Class libraries, we can use the timeout property in Function code declaration level:

  ```
  [Timeout("-1")]
  [Function("Your_Function_Name")]
  {
  xxxxxxx
  }
  ```
- Also, update the **extensionBundle** to the recent version which makes the functions bindings to right compatibility, replace `"version": "[2.*, 3.0.0)"` to `"version": "[3.3.0, 4.0.0)"`.

[image]